# Samsung Galaxy S2: Autorotation only in stand-by mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, auto-rotation, gyroscope

I have the problem with the auto-rotation since the GingerBread 2.3.6 and now with the ICS 4.0.3, now the rotation works only if I put in "stand by" the screen, then I rotate the phone and it rotates...the blue ball in calibration setting does not move...I tried the hard reset, the rooting (in gingerbread), the reflashing (GingerBread and ICS), nothing to do...There is only a strange fact the App GyroDroid when I had gingerbread the "linear acceleration test" did not work, now (ICS) it works...but it seems that my accelerometer works only in that test :-( What can it be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that home screens *DO NOT* rotate.

As well as this, developers can request their apps are only to be used in portrait mode - they therefore won't rotate automatically.

If you *really* want to rotate your screen, you can download the [Set Orientation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation) app, which will allow you to force your screen to rotate, based on a default orientation setting, or your sensor.

Comment: Oh, some home screens do -- mine does (GOLauncher EX), and AFAIK so does ADW. Some others might rotate as well. But the *Set Orientation* app might prove helpful; I cannot tell from my experience, but the app description sounds promising.